# Why рукопожатный?/ Почему говорится "рукопожатный"?

Tags: история-языка, морфология

The word itself is like a standard p.pt., except that such words can be in Russian either т- or н-ending. How come that рукопожатен has both affixes?

Само слово похоже на обычное причастие прошедшего времени - если не считать того факта, что в русском языке слова такого рода могут быть либо оканчивающимися на н, либо на т. Как получилось, что слово "рукопожатен" имеет сразу оба аффикса?

Comment: What do you mean by "both affixes"? Could you please mark them in the question?

Comment: @Quassnoi If I understand correctly, the OP compares `рукопожатный` to say `поддатый` and `подданный`.

Comment: @texnic: sure, but why "both" affixes?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Well, `т` and `н` together. But `т` is not a suffix of course. So I am not sure.

Comment: So what is т in that word? Cf. also with пожат\зажат\прижат, or with приятный\приятен (not with халатный\халатен).

Comment: Well, I am actually wrong. `т` is a suffix, already in the verb... So I think your question is perfectly valid, except that it is an adjective. See answer by @Yellow-Sky.

Comment: @Manjusri: there is no consensus on what is *-ть* in verbs: http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#3_5 For some reason *-чь* is unanimously treated as an ending, though etymologically it's exactly the same morpheme affected by the palatalizations: *мочь < могти*, *печь < пекти* etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Рукопожатный* is not a participle, it's a verbal adjective (*отглагольное прилагательное*).

It defines the ability of the noun defined to be an object to the verb in question.

From *Русская грамматика*:

> § 646. Прилагательные с суффиксом, представленным морфом `-н1` (фонемат. `|н|`; перед `|н|` беглая `|о|`) и рядом других морфов с конечной фонемой `|н|` имеют значение "характеризующийся отношением к действию, названному мотивирующим словом".
>
> …
>
> 2) "являющийся объектом действия", обычно с оттенком "способный стать объектом действия"
>
> …
>
> § 648. Все морфы этого суффикса выступают в структуре мотивированных прилагательных после согласных; при этом инф. основы мотивирующих глаголов преобразуются следующим образом:
>
> …
>
> 2) Путем наращения односложных корней на гласную: а) за счет финали `-|т1|-` в *знать - знатный (известный, знаменитый), слить - слитный, скрытный, занятный, понятный, внятный, необъятный* (везде перед морфом `-н1-`)

Comment: Will you specify the verb from which the word "рукопожатный" is derived?

Comment: @YellowSky: *пожать*

Comment: Then the morphological function of "руко-" becomes obscure. A prefix?..

Comment: @YellowSky: a root in a polyradical word

Comment: Then, "рукопожатный" is derived not from a verb, but from a noun and a verb merged into a single polyradical word. Besides, the second component, *пожатный, is not used as a separate word, only sometimes as shortening of "рукопожатный", and never as a part of other words.

Comment: @YellowSky: in your opinion, what are the words *словолитный* and *дроболитный*? They both are formed from phrases (a noun and a verb) and the verb form is unique to them.

Comment: These two words can well be adjectives derived from nouns *словолитьё and *дроболитьё. There are even worse cases, like "зубодробильный" - here neither a source noun nor a source verb can be found (-ль- looks strange in a verb form). I just want to understand if they are _derived_ from a word / 2 words, or, maybe, they are _constructed_ from morphemes to form those polyradical words, without the intermediate stage of noun or verb lemmas: рук+о+по+жа+т+н+ый, слов+о+ли+ть+ё.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7420/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-yellow-sky)

Answer (score 2):

Это не причастие, а прилагательное, поскольку образовано не от глагола, а от существительного `рукопожатие` при помощи типичного суффикса прилагательных -н-.

Слово является неологизмом, возникшем в советской диссидентской и российской либеральной среде. Происхождение, значение, примеры употребления и производные слова [приводятся тут](http://www.wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Comment: It is derived from a verb. This is a wrong answer.

Comment: Слово возникло не в либеральной или диссидентской среде, а придумано "Львом Щаранским" (псевдоним какого-то поцреота).