# Adjectives ending in -тный

Tags: этимология, морфология

Upon [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7420/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-yellow-sky) with YellowSky, a follow-up question arose:

> There are some adjectives ending in *-тный* which could be grammatically possibly originated from **both a noun and a verb with *-т-* not being a part of the verb's infinitive stem**.
>
> Of those adjectives, are there such which for semantic reasons can definitely be said to have originated from the noun and not from the verb?

Here are some examples:

- *Рукопожатный* can (theoretically) be derived both from *пожать руку* and *рукопожатие*, since  they define the same concept. Same with *кровопролитный, старожитный* etc.
- *Занятный* ("amusing, interesting") cannot be derived from *занятие* but only from *занимать* ("take one's attention, curiosity, interest"), since *занятие* does not have this metaphorical meaning. Same with *понятный* etc.
- *Приметный* ("related to omens, superstitions", as in *народно-приметный календарь*) is definitely originated from *примета* and not *приметить*, however, *-т-* here is a part of the verb's stem.
- *Рвотный* ("emetic") could only be originated from *рвота* and not *рвать*, because *рвать* lacks *-о-*. Same for *блевотный, тошнотный* etc.

Comment: What about блевота > блевотный, тошнота > тошнотный, рвота > рвотный? Corresponding verbs cannot be the source of derivation, those verbs don't have the -o-.

Comment: @YellowSky: sure they can't, that's why I don't consider them. I'm looking for words which (grammatically) could be derived from both a noun or a verb, but would exclude the verb for semantic reasons.

Comment: @YellowSky: theoretically, verbs ending in *-оть* could fit here, however, they acquire the other suffix when adjectivized: *-колоть > -кольный, -молоть > -мольный* etc. It's interesting if there are such words not originated due to the metathesis of liquids.

Comment: What about *разворотный-разворот-разворотить* or *воротный-ворота-воротить* where *воротить* means *вернуть к.-л.*?

Comment: @КуЪ: *воро-т-ить*, *-т-* is in the stem. The question deals with a very specific pattern, see the original question (http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/) and the discussion. The verbs that would fit here are *-жать / -жатный, -мять / -мятный, -пить / -питный, -лить / -литный, -жить / -житный, -быть / -бытный* and similar, without *-т-* before *-[V]ть*

Comment: I'm thinking about word _чётный_.  I can't really come up with a good explanation for what it originated from.  Possibly, from _счётный_ -> _счёт_, but I'm not too certain.

Comment: @AleksG: it's a calque of Latin *par* ("peer, equal") from *paritas* ("parity, equality"), which corresponds to CS *чета* ("gathering of peers"). Compare *он мне не чета* ("he's not of my station"), *сочетать* ("to match, to chord"). Anyway it has a *-т-* in the stem too.

Answer (score 2):

At first, word composition looks a bit more complicated.

An ending is only "ый" here.

"т" and "н" could be 2 suffixes or parts of suffixes (we wish, it is not part of a stem). "н" is definitive one, but suffix "т" doesn't seem to exist at all. It could be a part of a suffix.

**Adjective suffixes:**

"оват"/"овит" in "угловатый","деловитый". I cannot imagine any combination like "оватный", it just sounds unnatural.

Similar story with suffix "чат", "аст", "ат", "ист". There is no need to add another suffix after.

**Noun suffixes:**

"ет"("от") **example: доброта - добротный**

"ист" - i cannot imagine something with "истный", and it doesn't look really Russian. Adjectives are build usually with "истический". sounds more German.

"есть"("ость") **example: жалость - безжалостный**

http://irgali.narod.ru/files/znashenia_suffiksov.htm

Comment: So what is your answer? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Quassnoi as i tried to illustrate, that the question "originated from verb or noun" needs to be clarified. Because these verbs and nouns are originated from each other. Do you mean historical "facts about etymology" or "possibility to find some logical relation" ?

Comment: The examples help to clarify what I meant exactly. In the second example (*занятный*) the adjective originates from the verb and not a noun, though the two are definitely closest cognates.

Comment: @Quassnoi Ok, probably I've understood wrong before. I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but have you read the question? :)

Comment: @Quassnoi Sure. You wanted an adjective, originated from a noun, having "тный" but, "т" should be not part of a stem. 2 examples are given.

Comment: Quoting myself: "possibly originated from a noun OR a verb". From which verbs *добротный* and *безжалостный* could be originated? Please see the original question http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1877 for the background of this one.

Comment: @Quassnoi .. hmm .. so , wait a minute. You want to find a adjective "which can definitely be said to have originated from the noun" but at the same time possibly originated from a verb ?

**Definitely** originated from a noun but **possibly not**. I see some conflict it this definition.

Comment: @Quassnoi But as i see, your initial discussion was "Рукопожатный is a participle, or a verbal adjective".

Definitely verbal adjective. Difference between verbal adjective and participle is defined not by origination but by using. Because they often sound identical.

You cannot combine рукопожатный with ablative noun. Only "Он - рукопожатный". "Он рукопожатный кем-то/чем-то" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Grammar allows *занятный* to be originated both from noun *занятие* and verb *занять*, but semantics says it's originated from the verb. I'm looking for an adjective which would *grammatically* derivable from both but *semantically* only from the noun. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7827/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-stepan-stepanov)

Answer (score 0):

I think *рвотный* makes an exception here, while the rest of the adjectives shows a т + н combination of suffixes.

My guess is that these suffixes were first used to designate two different actants: т used to be a marker of (past) passive *participle*, like in Germanic languages, while н was to designate an *adjective* derived from a participle.

This participle/adjective distinction has survived up to day in modern Swedish language. Thus, т is a more ancient marker and н appeared later.

The т + н combination might appear in Russian during the period of distribution of т/н participles by their conjugation types.

Comment: I dont think its exception. Moreover that was the right example (see my answer). We have there suffix "от" wich is very popular добротный, рвотный, животный(not sure here, can be a stem), высотный, широтный, and so on ..

Comment: The suffix is -(V)т- like in рукопожатный, приметный, сытный. In some words, like in сиюминутный, it may even be a part of the word stem. The words you have listed also seem to expose the semantic combination of participle+adjective markers.

Comment: No, they cannot be understood as "participle-like". E.g. высотный is nothing that was risen or made high, it is something that is on height or has high height.

Comment: Высотный is something which has a quality of being built high, or having obtained высота as a main quality; добротный has got a lot of доброта; рвотный causes рвота;  животный has a lot of живот, or life; широтный has got a lot of широта as its main quality, etc. These words, however, should be divided into those which have -t- as a part of their stem and those which don't. Again, they are not exactly participles, but rather participle-like, where, roughly, -Vt- conveys the meaning of passive participle and the -n- that of adjective/active participle. Pls see the distribution of participles

Comment: ...and adjectives derived from participles in modern Swedish.

Comment: I have a bit another understanding of these words ))

verb - повышать, превышать. Participle-like adjectives - повышенный.
Высотный район - an area which is high. There was no process (verb), it was never low, and so on.

Широтный is even better example.
Широтный диапазон = дипапзон широт. Is not "wide" and is not "extended" at all.

Добротный doesn't have a lot of доброта. It is добро сделанный.

I've just used list of all suffixes. This list tells me "there is no suffix т" and "suffix от belongs to a noun"

Comment: Повышенный is a participle plus оный. Pls, do check the participles VS participle adjectives in Scandinavian languages.

Comment: Повышенный can be both.

Он платит повышенный налог. Adjective.
Налог, повышенный гос. думой, составил 15%. Participle.

Comment: Right, and all the words could have the *-тн- form before as participles, with later arbitrary assimilation тн => нн